# Automatically print PDF with Title, Date, and Time above Contents

Tags: pdf, printing, automation

Using any program or language, what will be easiest way to automatically print PDF file with its title, date, and time(as time of printing) above contents?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0w0SdCEZh8eWmRCaWRZc0d1Y0k/view?usp=sharing

Link is how i want prints to look to be.

Comment: Most languages have good PDF libraries - you can probably pick a language that will allow you to open a PDF, change the paper size and add some text. If you want to automatically send it to a printer too then that will depend on your OS and environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an annotation and set its attributes for print only, that is, no viewing on screen. This annotation could contain whatever content you want. You can use a PDF library to read the document properties and add such annotations.
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=220&t=Creating_Alternative_PDF_Content_For_Screen_and_Print